# React native collapsible malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different

Tags: react-native

I'm using [oblador/react-native-collapsible](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible)

and when I try to toggle the collapsible component I get a warning message **Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.**

**Here is my code:**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isCollapsed: true
    };
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({ isCollapsed: !this.state.isCollapsed });
  }

render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggle}>
           <Icon
            active
            type="FontAwesome"
            name="caret-down"
       />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <Collapsible collapsed={this.state.isCollapsed}>
        <View>
          <Text>Hello World!</Text>
        </View>
       </Collapsible>

 </SafeAreaView>

);
}
```

I followed the example code [here](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible/blob/master/Example/App.js)

Can anyone help me solve this? Thank you!

Comment: What version of `React` & `React-Native` are you using? Is it a warning or an error?

Comment: @nopassport1 "react": "16.8.3", "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz", it used to be an error, but now it shows a warning with the same message

Comment: Why are you using `react-native` from `expo`?

Comment: I'm new with react-native, I just followed the instructor from an online course using expo.

Comment: Have you tried updating your dependencies & changing your `react-native` version to the latest one?

Comment: @nopassport1 Yes, I've tried it already.